# I need to splice an array at a certian key then add all values before the key to the end of a new array php

Tags: php, arrays

For example I want to splice the following array at key 57, placing it in the first position of a new array and place all keys before 57 to the end of the new array.

```
Array ( [0] => ~ [1] => i [2] => X [3] => M [4] => c [5] => E [6] => [ [7] => Q [8] => 1 [9] => . [10] => b [11] => 8 [12] => G [13] => g [14] => \ [15] => @ [16] => 6 [17] => N [18] => k [19] => q [20] => O [21] => K [22] => _ [23] => { [24] => J [25] => T [26] => m [27] => a [28] => 4 [29] => * [30] => P [31] => n [32] => ) [33] => ] [34] => p [35] => w [36] => x [37] => ( [38] => r [39] => B [40] => U [41] => V [42] => = [43] => z [44] => e [45] => 5 [46] => v [47] => ' [48] => S [49] => Z [50] => L [51] => 3 [52] => 9 [53] => % [54] => > [55] => j [56] => / [57] => $ [58] => 2 [59] => Y [60] => # [61] => D [62] => I [63] => A [64] => o [65] => | [66] => F [67] => , [68] => } [69] => ? [70] => + [71] => C [72] => " [73] => 0 [74] => : [75] => u [76] => & [77] => t [78] => 7 [79] => s [80] => h [81] => ^ [82] => d [83] => [84] => f [85] => H [86] => - [87] => ; [88] => ! [89] => ` [90] => < [91] => R [92] => W [93] => l [94] => y )
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, this should be easily achieved using `array_slice()` and `array_reverse()`. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here's what you need:

```
<?php
$before = array_slice($arr, 0, 57);
$after = array_slice($arr, 57);
$newArray = array_merge($after, $before);
```

This will slice the array at the 57th item, and swap them.